# Approval process, send to Role for approval

Tags: approval-process

in an approval process I want to send for approval to members of a role, but the only possibilities is to send to users or the manager of the submitter. Any ideas how I can achive this?
Thank you

Comment: are you having approval on custom object? If yes, you can try assigning approver to a queue.

Comment: Unfortunately, my approvals are on Account and Opportunity objects and I can't create queues